# Border not smooth while making rounded

Tags: html, css

I have added button with rounded corner. It will be little bit blurred with circle button.

```css
.btn {
  border: 1px solid #4278ae;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">Test</a>
```

[image: looks like now]

I want look like this flat and smooth. How can i achieve this? 
[image]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "blurred"? It looks fine to me (Firefox Quantum).

Comment: @lalitbhakuni you are so clever!! :|

Answer (score 3):

`1px` is just not visible to our eyes. The code has no issue but you can use `2px` for it to look better.

As you know pixels work like this,

[image]

Therefore we see it as if the curve is not smooth/clear.

```css
.btn {
  border: 2px solid #4278ae;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">Test</a>
```

Comment: nice explanation

Answer (score 1):

Use Box-Shadow property in place of border:

`box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px #4278ae;`

in place of

```
border: 1px solid #4278ae;
```

It looks more clear

Comment: hmmm
it looks better thanks mate.. Still looking if possible to make same